# Webpack 'publicPath' with express static

Tags: express, webpack

I'm trying to understand webpack `output.publicPath` now. I'm reading [webpack official docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) now, but it dosen't help me.

So here is `webpack.config.js`

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: '/dist',
    publicPath: '/assets'  // what's this for?
  },

  plugins: [
    // ...
  ]
};
```

So i guess, this makes all files reference `/assets` which is set to publicPath. like prefix.

When if i want to server static file in `/assets` with express server, i should makes `/assets` as static like `app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'))` .

Then what is the purpose of `publicPath` ? is it just prefix for path?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but in case anyone else looked at this question like me and wished it had an answer -

This `publicPath` is used by webpack as an alias by which you can access your built files. When you also attach it to express static file serving as you've done above, you allow any files placed there by webpack to be requested via that path.

For example, if you have `/assets` as your `publicPath` and a file `foo.js` that is built during your webpack build, you can then access it by hitting `localhost:[port]/assets/foo.js`

Answer (score 1):

I've spent so much time trying to wrap my head around `path` vs `publicPath` that my head nearly explodes. Here is what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong):

`publicPath` specifies the URL that Webpack needs to reference from the perspective of the `index.html` file.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets')
    publicPath: '/assets/
  }
}
```

This means the bundle is located at the `dist/assets` directory in your file system, but a request to it will look like `localhost:3000/assets/bundle.js`.

Inside the `index.html`, the script tag will look like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bundle.js"></script>`

It is even more important when you serve assets from external resources like a CDN.

What you do with Express `static` middleware is irrelevant AFAIK. But I still set the `assets` folder as the root directory from which to serve static files.